# Populate a thrid model, pulling data from different model with an after_create callback on User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, callback

I have 3 models, User, member_role & member. I need to use after_create callback on User model and populate the member model fetching the role from member_role model.

Would appreciate any help regarding how I can accomplish that.

My Member_role model loos like

> 1 - admin
>   2 - teacher
>   3- student
>   4 - so on

And mr member Model looks like

> member_id
>   user_id
>   member_role_id

Need to populate Member model with an after_create callback on User model.

Here is my Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150930061155) do

  create_table "member_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "role",       limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
    t.integer  "user_id",        limit: 4
    t.integer  "member_role_id", limit: 4
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "provider",               limit: 255,   default: "email", null: false
    t.string   "uid",                    limit: 255,   default: "",      null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255,   default: "",      null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,     default: 0,       null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
    t.string   "confirmation_token",     limit: 255
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email",      limit: 255
    t.string   "name",                   limit: 255
    t.string   "nickname",               limit: 255
    t.string   "image",                  limit: 255
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255
    t.text     "tokens",                 limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

Comment: Can you give us `schema.rb` too?

Comment: @dimakura please check I have added my schema at the bottom

Comment: @dimakura Thanks a ton it works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the default `MemberRole` is the first one:

```
class User
  after_create :assign_member_role

  private
  def assign_member_role
    mr = MemberRole.first # default MR
    Member.create!(user_id: self.id, member_role_id: mr.id)
  end
end
```